# Magento 2.1.9 Admin Panel Styles & JS not loading correctly

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel

I have installed Magento 2.1.9 using magento installer `https://magento.com/tech-resources/download`.

All tables on admin panel loading as the attached image. Any solution for mentioned error?

[image: Magento 2.1.9 Fresh Installed Admin Panel]

Comment: you need to redeploy static content

Comment: I did. but not fixed

Answer (score 1):

Run Below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cahce:clean
```

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Answer (score 1):

check permission of pub/static and var directories

Comment: pub/static and var - 755 permission

Comment: if it has 755 permission then deploy static content and refresh magento cache

Answer (score 1):

I removed CloudFlare cache & auto minify option. Now it's loading without error. Thank you for all support

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue :

Open    app/etc/di.xml

Change :
`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">`

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

To:

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

delete all folders in pub/static ( make sure don't delete .htaccess file )

and then :

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cahce:clean

hope it will start working